# Jquery plugin roundabout: All the divs overlap

Tags: jquery, css

I want divs to round about using the roundabout jquery plugin, as well as the roundabout shapes plugin.
I cannot figure out why all the divs overlap!

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kampfkuchen/qU45h/6/

I guess the problem is somewhere in the css:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: auto;
min-width: 900px;
height: auto;
background-color: #000000;
}
.roundabout-container {
list-style: none;
position: absolute;
margin: 300px;
}

#company {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
}

#portfolio {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

#blog {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Help is highly appreciated!
Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: You're not including any of the roundabout JS or CSS external resources in your fiddle. If you can add those it would be easier to identify the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I updated it!